# Alternating sequence of Lebesgue integrable functions implies the sum of the integrals is equal to the integral of the sum.

Tags: sequences-and-series, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

A question from a past analysis qual at my university reads: Let $f_n$ be Lebesgue integrable on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $|f_n(x)|\searrow 0$ a.e. Also assume that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$ is an alternating series for almost every $x$. Prove that
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_\mathbb{R} f_n(x)dx$$

My first thought was to show that $\sum_1^\infty \int_\mathbb{R} |f_n|<\infty$ and then use the dominated convergence theorem. However, the sequence of functions $f_n(x)=\frac{(-1)^n}{\log(n)}\chi_{[-1,1]}(x)$ satisfies the hypothesis, but $\sum_2^\infty \int_\mathbb{R} |f_n|dx=2\sum_2^\infty  1/\log(n) =\infty$.  The function $g(x):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$ converges a.e. (alternating series test) and $g_n(x):=\sum_1^n f_k(x)\rightarrow g(x)$, but it's not necessarily a monotone sequence so I can't use the monotone convergence theorem. Using Fatou's lemma, I think I can show if $\int_\mathbb{R} g(x)dx=\infty$, then both sides of the equality above is equal to $\infty$, so I can move on to the case where $\int_\mathbb{R} g(x)dx<\infty$. But I get stuck here, how should I proceed?

Comment: Show that, except on some null set, you have $\bigl\lvert \sum_{n = 1}^k f_n(x)\bigr\rvert \leqslant \lvert f_1(x)\rvert$.

Comment: Define $g_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n f_k(x)$. By hypothesis, each $g_n$ is integrable and $|g_n(x)|\leq |f_1(x)|$ (the hint above) where $f_1$ is integrate by hypothesis. Then use the dominated convergence theorem to get the result. Is that it?

Comment: Yes, that's it (modulo the null set).

Comment: So simple, I was just overthinking it. Thanks!